# Preload that waits for a function to execute

Tags: javascript, html, css, preload

I'm working on a preload for an article abstracts page. I manage to get the preload to show, but the first time the page loads, the preload disappears before the article summaries are fully loaded. It takes about 5 seconds for summaries to load after the preload disappears. Behavior that is not wanted.
The second time onwards it works as desired

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(1);
    });

    p2.then(function (value) {
        $('#preloader .inner').fadeOut();
        return value + 1;
    }).then(function (value) {
        PegaListaPosts();
        return value + 1;
    }).then(function (value) {
        $('#preloader').delay(10).fadeOut('slow');
        return value + 1;
    }).then(function (value) {
        $('body').delay(10).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
    });
    //$('#preloader .inner').fadeOut();
    //var con = await PegaListaPosts();
    //$('#preloader').delay(10).fadeOut('slow');
    //$('body').delay(10).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
});
```

```
function PegaListaPosts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Blog/PegaResumoPost",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var lista = data.resumosPosts;

            if (data.culturaAtual == 2) {
                    CarregarResumos(lista, data.culturaAtual);
            }
            else if (data.culturaAtual == 1) {
                    CarregarResumos(lista, data.culturaAtual);
            }
            else {
                    CarregarResumos(lista, data.culturaAtual);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: `PegaListaPosts` doesn't return anything, not even a Promise - also, not sure why you're using all those `.then` where there is no promises at all

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows.
I put the "PegaListaPosts()" function in Window onload, and inside the called function, I call the preload functions.
The code was like this:

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    PegaListaPosts();
});

function PegaListaPosts() {
    $('#preloader .inner').fadeOut();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Blog/PegaResumoPost",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data)
        {
            var lista = data.resumosPosts;

            if (data.culturaAtual == 2) {
                CarregarResumos(lista, data.culturaAtual);
            }
            else if (data.culturaAtual == 1) {
                CarregarResumos(lista, data.culturaAtual);
            }
            else {
                CarregarResumos(lista, data.culturaAtual);
            }
            $('#preloader').delay(10).fadeOut('slow');
            $('body').delay(10).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#preloader').delay(10).fadeOut('slow');
            $('body').delay(10).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
            alert('Não foi possível carregar os resumos dos posts!');
        }
    });
}
```

With this, the preload only disappears when the article summaries have all been loaded.